# parse error in class - works ok localhost not on website

Tags: php

I have a PHP library that I have downloaded - it is a popular library that is used on a lot of sites. I run this locally on my localhost and all ok. I then tried to load it to website and run it there and getting a parse error.

I cant work out why it runs on my localhost and not on website - can you please take a look and see if it is something obvious ? maybe php.ini setting I need to set or something else ?

The error is

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/phoenixs/public_html/smsGateway.php on line 14

Here is the library and I have highlighted line 14.:

line 14 is 
return $this->makeRequest('/api/v3/contacts/create','POST',['name' => $name, 'number' => $number]);

- I have put the calling script below this

  `class SmsGateway {

      static $baseUrl = "https://smsgateway.me";


      function __construct($email,$password) {
          $this->email = $email;
          $this->password = $password;
      }

      function createContact ($name,$number) {
          return $this->makeRequest('/api/v3/contacts/create','POST',['name' => $name, 'number' => $number]);
      }

      function getContacts ($page=1) {
         return $this->makeRequest('/api/v3/contacts','GET',['page' => $page]);
      }

      function getContact ($id) {
          return $this->makeRequest('/api/v3/contacts/view/'.$id,'GET');
      }


      function getDevices ($page=1)
      {
          return $this->makeRequest('/api/v3/devices','GET',['page' => $page]);
      }

      function getDevice ($id)
      {
          return $this->makeRequest('/api/v3/devices/view/'.$id,'GET');
      }

      function getMessages($page=1)
      {
          return $this->makeRequest('/api/v3/messages','GET',['page' => $page]);
      }

      function getMessage($id)
      {
          return $this->makeRequest('/api/v3/messages/view/'.$id,'GET');
      }

      function sendMessageToNumber($to, $message, $device, $options=[]) {
          $query = array_merge(['number'=>$to, 'message'=>$message, 'device' => $device], $options);
          return $this->makeRequest('/api/v3/messages/send','POST',$query);
      }

      function sendMessageToManyNumbers ($to, $message, $device, $options=[]) {
          $query = array_merge(['number'=>$to, 'message'=>$message, 'device' => $device], $options);
          return $this->makeRequest('/api/v3/messages/send','POST', $query);
      }

      function sendMessageToContact ($to, $message, $device, $options=[]) {
          $query = array_merge(['contact'=>$to, 'message'=>$message, 'device' => $device], $options);
          return $this->makeRequest('/api/v3/messages/send','POST', $query);
      }

      function sendMessageToManyContacts ($to, $message, $device, $options=[]) {
          $query = array_merge(['contact'=>$to, 'message'=>$message, 'device' => $device], $options);
          return $this->makeRequest('/api/v3/messages/send','POST', $query);
      }

      function sendManyMessages ($data) {
          $query['data'] = $data;
          return $this->makeRequest('/api/v3/messages/send','POST', $query);
      }

      private function makeRequest ($url, $method, $fields=[]) {

          $fields['email'] = $this->email;
          $fields['password'] = $this->password;

          $url = smsGateway::$baseUrl.$url;

          $fieldsString = http_build_query($fields);


          $ch = curl_init();

          if($method == 'POST')
          {
              curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
              curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fieldsString);
          }
          else
          {
              $url .= '?'.$fieldsString;
          }

          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER , false);  // we want headers
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

          $result = curl_exec ($ch);

          $return['response'] = json_decode($result,true);

          if($return['response'] == false)
              $return['response'] = $result;

          $return['status'] = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

          curl_close ($ch);

          return $return;
      }
  }`


  ?>

and here is the calling script:

```
  <?php


include "smsGateway.php";
```

$smsGateway = new SmsGateway('user', 'password');

```
$deviceID = 22233;

$number = '+64210419805';
$message = 'hi gg 3';

$result = $smsGateway->sendMessageToNumber($number, $message, $deviceID);

print_r($result);

?>
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you running on your website  server? Short array syntax requires PHP >= 5.4.0

Comment: Thank you so much Mark - it was PHP 5.3 and updated it so all working now. I really appreciate your help.